# return sibling with index

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, dom-traversal

I am trying to select a sibling of a ul by index. The user answers a question and if wrong the correct answer is highlighted.

My code goes up one level and tried to find the `<li>` by index

```
el.parent('ul').eq(2).addClass('correct');
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

```
el.parent('ul').children('li').eq(2).addClass('correct');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#ulid li").eq(indexNumberHere).addClass('correct')
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.